# How to compile new source code in vuejs boilerplate using webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, vue-cli-3

I'd like to ask you something easy which is difficult for me.
It's about vuejs compile based on webpack.

I am a newbie in vuejs especially in this boilerplate(https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate).
I want to make an app based on this boilerplate.

I installed this boilerplate and then added "vuetify" (responsive GUI plugin) to make an app. With responsive UI
it was not easy but finally they are working together.

[Image showing vue and vuetify working together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C39aF.png)

When i added vuetify, helloWorld.vue is also added in ./src/components automatically,
but it is not complied (transpiled) so whenever i run "yarn dev" to launch dev server,  I see a message like below:

> ./HelloWorld in
> ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/app.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

I want to know how I can compile HelloWorld.vue and make it included in output file like app.js.
Additionally, moving HelloWordl.vue to ./src was not working as well.

I just want to know small hints for that.

Thanks in advance.
June, Chung

Comment: did you install npm?

Comment: of course, as i mentioned, they are working together well

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason.

I added statement like this in app.vue

> import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld'

it made an error( it must be ./components/HelloWorld.vue )

I thought it is okay when I import the component without its extension.